# Java File input error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 22427275

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, data-structures, readfile

This is my error run:

```
Welcome to Hero University
Teach well
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 22427275
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:964)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:403)
    at university_info.UniversityDriver.main(UniversityDriver.java:24)
```

MY Code: Also I have a txt file that I am trying to read the info from. but I cat figure out how.

```
package university_info;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UniversityDriver{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       University u_city=new University("Hero","Teach well");
       System.out.println("Welcome to "+u_city.universityName+" University");  
   System.out.println(u_city.motto);
     
  
   // retrieving data from external file on startup.....
   ArrayList<Person> al=new ArrayList<Person>();
   try{
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("fileName.txt");
       ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
       al = (ArrayList<Person>) ois.readObject();
       ois.close();
       }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
           System.out.println("File not found exception");
       }catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
          
       }
  
   Object[] array=new Object[al.size()];
   array=al.toArray(array);
  
   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       u_city.people[i]=(Person)array[i];
   }
      
   System.out.println("What would you like to do");
   System.out.println("Enter 'hire' to hire a new faculty member. ");
   System.out.println("Enter 'admit' to admit a new student ");
   System.out.println("Enter 'find student' to list information about a student");
   System.out.println("Enter 'find faculty' to list information about a faculty member");
   System.out.println("Enter 'list students' to list the names of all students.");
   System.out.println("Enter 'list faculty' to list the names of faculty members");
   System.out.println("Enter 'quit' to end this program and save data");
  
   //-------------------->
  
  
   Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean run= true;
   while(run){
      
   String s= in.nextLine();
   if(s.equals("quit")){
       run=false;
       //save data in extenal file
   try{
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileName.txt");
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
          oos.writeObject(u_city.people);
          oos.close();
      }catch(IOException ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
     
   if(s.equals("hire")){
       u_city.hire();
   }
   if(s.equals("admit")){
       u_city.admit();
   }
   if(s.equals("find_student")){
       System.out.println("What is the student's first name?");
       String fn=in.nextLine();
       System.out.println("What is the student's last name?");
       String ln=in.nextLine();
       Student temp=u_city.findStudent(fn, ln);
       if(temp==null){
           System.out.println("Student not found");
       }else{
           temp.Details();
       }
   }
   if(s.equals("find_faculty")){
       System.out.println("What is the faculty's first name?");
       String fn=in.nextLine();
       System.out.println("What is the faculty's last name?");
       String ln=in.nextLine();
       Faculty temp=u_city.findFaculty(fn, ln);
       if(temp==null){
           System.out.println("faculty not found");
       }
   }
  
   if(s.equals("list_student")){
       Person[] temp= u_city.getStudents();
       for(int i=0;i<=temp.length;i++){
           System.out.println(temp[i].firstName+" "+temp[i].lastName);
       }
         
   }
   if(s.equals("list_faculty")){
       Person[] temp= u_city.getFaculty();
       for(int i=0;i<=temp.length;i++){
           System.out.println(temp[i].firstName+" "+temp[i].lastName);
       }     
         
   }
   }
  
}
}
```

this is my project prompt:

You will be creating a program that adds, queries, and stores university information on
students and faculty.
You program must have the following classes: UniversityDriver, University, Person,
Student, and Faculty. These classes must follow the specification provided in this
document.
You must submit the java files corresponding to these classes on the Canvas submission
page on or before the due date. Your project submission must compile in order to be a
valid submission. Submissions that do not compile will not receive any credit.

Initial University Data:

```
Faculty: (first name, last name, month-birth, day-birth, year-birth, course 1, course 2, …
course n )
"Bruce", "Wayne", 9, 27, 1995, “Bayesian Logic”, “Artificial Intelligence”, “Hardware 
Design”
“Diana","Prince", 11, 5, 2006, "Hardware Design", “FPGA Programming”, “Embedded
Systems”
“Barbara”, “Gordon”, 5, 23, 1980, “Probability”, “Signal Processing”, “Advance
Algorithms”
"Charles","Xavier", 11, 5, 1966, “Signal Processing”, “Embedded Systems”, “Parallel
Programming”
Students: (first name, last name, month-birth, day-birth, year-birth, major)
"Billy", "Baston", 7, 12, 1990, "Information Analytics"
"Carol", "Danvers", 4, 9, 1992, "Quantum Computing"
"Clark", "Kent", 5, 5, 1994 , "Hardware Architecture"
"Kara", "Zorel", 4, 13, 1989, "Hardware Architecture"
"Peter","Parker", 6, 25, 1997, "Quantum Computing"
"Tony","Stark", 2, 2, 2004, "Hardware Architecture"
"Stephen","Strange", 12, 15, 1976, "Quantum Computing"
"Bruce","Banner", 9, 9, 2000, “Undecided”
```

MY TXT FILE IS LOCATED HERE WITH THIS INFO

[image: location]

WITH THIS INFO:

```
"Bruce", "Wayne", 9, 27, 1995, “Bayesian Logic”, “Artificial Intelligence”, “Hardware Design” 
“Diana","Prince", 11, 5, 2006, "Hardware Design", “FPGA Programming”, “Embedded Systems” 
“Barbara”, “Gordon”, 5, 23, 1980, “Probability”, “Signal Processing”, “Advance Algorithms” 
"Charles","Xavier", 11, 5, 1966, “Signal Processing”, “Embedded Systems”, “Parallel Programming”
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `ObjectInputStream` to read a file that was not created using `ObjectOutputStream`.  That approach won't work.

Clue: the number `22427275` is in hexadecimal.  When you decode it by doing a hex to ASCII lookup, you get the characters `'"'`, `'B'`, `'r'`, and `'u'`.  Does that look familiar?

A valid Object serialization will start with `aced0005` in hexadecimal.  (The `0xaced` is the object serialization format's "magic number" and `0x0005` is the current format version number.)

I suggest that you use `Scanner` or a CSV reader library to read the file.